# How does the subtraction of the logit maximum improve learning?

Tags: deep-learning, logit, tensorflow, keras, softmax

My question comes from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560420/deep-learning-implementation-in-tensorflow-or-keras-give-drastic-different-resul) answered on Stackoverflow; the Keras implemantion of [`softmax` activation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560420/deep-learning-implementation-in-tensorflow-or-keras-give-drastic-different-resul) is customized to subtract the maximum value of the different logits:

```
def softmax(x, axis=-1):
    # when x is a 2 dimensional tensor
    e = K.exp(x - K.max(x, axis=axis, keepdims=True))
    s = K.sum(e, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    return e / s
```

When using Tensorflow with the normal implementation of [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function), it means doing the following operation prior to the `softmax` call:

```
logits = logits - tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_max(logits, axis=-1), -1)
```

**Question:** How is it that subtracting the max of the logits helps learning? I don't get it.

**Subsidiary question:** How come the Keras implement knew this hack? Is there any publication related to this discovery?

Answer (score 11):

This is a simple trick to improve the numerical stability. As you probably know, exponential function grows very fast, and so does the magnitude of any numerical errors. This trick is based on the following equality:

$$\frac{e^{x+c}}{e^{x+c}+e^{y+c}} =  \frac{e^x e^c}{e^x e^c+e^y e^c} = \frac{e^x e^c}{e^c (e^x+e^y)} = \frac{e^x}{e^x+e^y},$$

where $c$ is the maximum which you are subtracting. As you can see, you can subtract any value without changing the softmax output. Selecting the maximum is a convenient way to ensure numerical stability.

Comment: To add: The history of this is quite long, it even has its own wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp